# Lateral movement while on VPN

Tags: malware, vpn, virus, access-control

Now that everyone is working from home using VPN, if infected by any malware, is lateral movement possible?

Comment: A VPN is essentially an extension of the internal network. Thus it is not unlikely that lateral movement into this internal network is possible. Even without a VPN lateral movement would be possible, starting from the infected machine to machines in the same network, on the internet etc

Comment: This is far too broad to be answerable. It's like asking if you can hack a computer that is connected to the internet.

Comment: It not like there's a mechanism to take over the Windows Active Directory Domain Controller and from there grab every machine on the network ... oh wait ... *Zerologon CVE-2020-1472* . ☣

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Some VPN will place all connected computers on the same net, without client isolation, thus you could jump from one computer of an employee to another (and from those to their home network, too!). Even if you can't do lateral movement between clients, it may be possible between different servers to which those users connect to.

Comment: I'd add more highlight to that first line. Lots of people are using "VPNs".

Comment: I'm not sure what you want highlighted, @schroeder

Comment: Just that it really depends on the type of VPN and the networking that is configured. A browser-based VPN is different from a site-to-site VPN, etc.